# Extract audio from HDMI signal and output to DVI-D & analog audio?

Tags: audio, hdmi, dvi, edid

I'm trying extract audio from an HDMI signal. Specifically, the monitor I'm using has no speakers and only has a DVI-D input, and I would like to play the audio track on a set of external speakers.

I purchased some cheap [HDMI audio extractor](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/Hign-Quality-MINI-HDMI2HDMI-AUDIO-and-Audio-Converter-with-1080p-HDMI-to-HDMI-with-Audio-QbO/32455613908.html?spm=2114.01010208.3.2.Sm0sbo&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_1_116_10065_117_10068_114_115_113_10000009_10084_10083_10080_10082_10081_10060_10061_10062_10056_10055_10037_10054_10033_10059_10032_10099_10078_10079_10077_427_426_10103_10073_10102_10096_10052_10107_10050_10106_10051,searchweb201603_2,afswitch_5&btsid=7d718c11-2474-4b71-bb62-aff447f21356) (HDMI-in, HDMI & 3.5mm audio out), and it works with my regular TV that has HDMI inputs, but not with my monitor setup (video signal passes through, no analog audio output). Is this behavior I should expect?

That is, by using an HDMI to DVI-D adapter for the output, is the audio channel somehow no longer being requested/sent through the HDMI cable, so that the extractor can no longer intercept the audio signal?

Or is there some other cheap alternative hack I can try?

Comment: 'cheap alternative hack' - route the audio elsewhere in software, using your system's sound manager... the same as everyone else does. Looks to me like you're trying to over-complicate a simple everyday task.

Comment: I wish, only I'm trying to extract audio from an inherently HDMI device (e.g. Chromecast, FireStick, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

I think this behavior is expected. As best I can tell, the Extended Display Identification Data (EDID) is exchanged between the HDMI source and the monitor; since the source detects the monitor does not support audio, no audio channel is transmitted. Depending on the source, there may be a way to [force a certain signal type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/jj133967(v=vs.85).aspx).

It looks like you can spoof EDID using something like [this](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/HDMI-EDID-Emulator-HDMI-EDID-Feeder-HDMI-Doctor-for-Handshake-Problems-Source-and-Display-3D-4kX2k/32698303650.html?spm=2114.01010208.3.117.ADAJR4&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_1_116_10065_117_10068_114_115_113_10000009_10084_10083_10080_10082_10081_10060_10061_10062_10056_10055_10037_10054_10033_10059_10032_10099_10078_10079_10077_427_426_10103_10073_10102_10096_10052_10107_10050_10106_10051-10051_114,searchweb201603_2,afswitch_5&btsid=25acbf37-8bfb-4a76-8f81-1e829e995d94) or possibly [this](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/HDMI1-4-HDCP1-4-Version-HDMI-to-HDMI-Audio-Converter-With-Optical-Coaxial-3-5mm-Audio/32566082208.html?spm=2114.01010208.3.48.IqqWpT&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_1_116_10065_117_10068_114_115_113_10000009_10084_10083_10080_10082_10081_10060_10061_10062_10056_10055_10037_10054_10033_10059_10032_10099_10078_10079_10077_427_426_10103_10073_10102_10096_10052_10107_10050_10106_10051,searchweb201603_2,afswitch_5&btsid=2862188b-a417-4da8-9dc7-5cee8de04ea6).